# How could i send a property of my class into function

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a function, where i could send all objects of all types of my project and it should iterate over properties and output their values:

```
public void ShowMeAll(IEnumerable<object> items);

IEnumerable<Car> _cars = repository.GetAllCars();
ShowMeAll(_cars);

IEnumerable<House> _houses = repository.GetAllHouses();
ShowMeAll(_houses);
```

Ok, for example, it's so. Now, i'd like to send into my ShowMeAll function a property, which over i'd like to OrderBy my items and then output. What is the most correct way to do this with a parameter of function?

Comment: @FSoul1 do you mean send in a property that you would like to show all on like ShowMeAll(_houses, SquareFootage) or using the order by on a property of an existing?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to let LINQ do that for you, via [the OrderBy() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx). For example:

```cs
IEnumerable<Car> _cars = repository.GetAllCars();
ShowMeAll(_cars.OrderBy(car => car.Make));

IEnumerable<House> _houses = repository.GetAllHouses();
ShowMeAll(_houses.OrderBy(house => house.SquareFootage));
```

That way, you remove the requirement for `ShowMeAll` to be aware of the properties of the objects passed in. Since you're passing `List<object>`, I assume that's desired. :)

Comment: But i'd like to variate a property which over i could make OrderBy and implement it into function.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void ShowMeAll<TClass>(IEnumerable<TClass> items, string property)
{
    PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(TClass));
    PropertyDescriptor targetProperty = properties.Find(property, true);

    if (targetProperty == null)
    {
        // Your own error handling
    }

    IEnumerable<TClass> sortedItems = items.OrderBy( a => targetProperty.GetValue(a));

    // Your own code to display your sortedItems
}
```

You would call the method like this:

```
ShowMeAll<Car>(_cars, "Make");
```

I've left out the error handling because I do not know what your requirements are

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void ShowMeAll<TClass>(IEnumerable<TClass> items, string property )
{
    // 1. Discover property type ONCE using reflection
    // 2. Create a dynamic method to access the property in a strongly typed fashion
    // 3. Cache the dynamic method for later use

    // here, my dynamic method is called dynamicPropertyGetter
    IEnumerable<TClass> sortedItems = items.OrderBy( o => dynamicPropertyGetter( o ) );
}
```

Dynamic methods (easier than they look, and 50-100x faster than reflection in my tests): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exczf7b9.aspx

Expression builders can also get the job done: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.expressionbuilder.aspx

Answer (score 0):

kind of this?

```
public void Test()
{
    var o = new[] {new {Name = "test", Age = 10}, new {Name = "test2", Age = 5}};
    ShowMeAll(o, i => i.Age);
}

public void ShowMeAll<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, object> keySelector)
{
    items.OrderBy(keySelector)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(t => Console.WriteLine(t));
}
```